# sqlite select query with foreign key for another table

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, sqlite.net

I am working on a project with xamarin android using the sqlite.net library.  I have a select query that will execute and create a collection of custom objects called worker :

```cs
var command = conn.CreateCommand("SELECT * FROM tblWorkers");
var results = command.ExecuteQuery<Worker>();
ObservableCollection<Worker> workers = new ObservableCollection<Worker>(results);
return workers;
```

One of the columns is a foreign key and I need to get a value from that table just wondering what the best way to do that is.  The foreign key on the data table tblWorkers is TitleID  On that table is a varchar(datatable : tblTitles column : Title - nvarchar)  I need to retrieve just wondering what the best way to do that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
var command = conn.CreateCommand("SELECT * FROM tblWorkers LEFT JOIN tblTitles ON tblWorkers.TitleID = tblTitles.id");
```

Now, the above will work, but in general you'll want to avoid `SELECT *` usage.  Only get the fields you want.  Ideally, something like this...

```cs
var command = conn.CreateCommand("SELECT tblWorkers.SomeFieldYouWant, tblWorkers.SomeOtherFieldYouWant, ... , tblTitles.Title FROM tblWorkers LEFT JOIN tblTitles ON tblWorkers.TitleID = tblTitles.id");
```

Comment: I was looking at using a join.  Out of curiosity why would I want to avoid using *?

Comment: Short answer: **Performance**.  You shouldn't return fields you don't need because you are requiring more work to be accomplished than required.  Even if right now you're using every field, I still personally recommend explicitly listing every field.  Envision a future where you change the underlying data schema for something completely unrelated and add 50 new columns.  Your old code will now be working to return those as well, and a part of your app that has behaved for years and hasn't been modified suddenly feels more sluggish. For more info, search around - I'm at the character limit!

Comment: Ok I got ya.  By the way I received an error of ambiguous column name: TitleID.

Comment: Good answer, and nice explanation about performance. Also, @Bob'sBurgers the ambiguous column name means TitleID exists in both tables and you didn't specify which table to select it from. Make sure your column list has something like `SELECT tblWorkers.titleID` and not just `SELECT TitleID`.

Comment: Ah, then TitleID must exist as a field name in both tables.  Also not best practice, but can be worked around by fully qualifying which one you want using `TableName.FieldName` format.  I'll update the answer in just a second accordingly...

Comment: It did exist  in both @LDMJoe had to call the different table names in both.